# BASH скрипт + переданный параметр + asterisk -rx

Tags: bash, asterisk, zabbix

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь создать небольшой скриптик для Asterisk под мониторинг Zabbix.
В скрипте будет прописано 'sip show ', а что show будет передаваться параметром с Zabbix, т.е. аргументом в скрипт. peers registry users....
Если просто запускать скрипт без передачи команды с кодом:

```
./script.sh
asterisk -rx "sip show registry"
```

все нормально выполняется и выводится нужная инфа, если же вместо выполняемой команды поставить аргумент, то скрипт не выполняется.

```
/script.sh registry
asterisk -rx "sip show $1"

или 

command=$1
asterisk -rx "sip show $command"
```

Выходит ошибка поиска команды:

```
for other possible commands)ow registry
```

Этот вывод есть огрызок от выполнения команды, если у астериска нет такой команды.
Т.е., допустим

```
asterisk -rx "sip show uncknown_command"
```

Выведет:

```
No such command 'sip show uncknown_command' (type 'core show help sip show uncknown_command' for other possible commands)
```

Вопрос в том, что я делаю не так? И как заставить скрипт получать переданный аргумент и передавать его в команду астериску?

Comment: Возможно в скрипте окончания строк как в Windows, а не как в Linux (или в скрипте, откуда вызывается этот скрипт).

Comment: Попробуйте `command="$(sed 's/\r//' <<< ${1})";
asterisk -rx "sip show $command"`, если сработает, то проблема действительно в возврате каретки

Comment: Супер!! Спасибо! Целый день бьюсь и так так пробовал, а проблема то на 5 секунд... Да заменил виндовое CRLF на UNIXовое LF и все выполнилось как надо.

Comment: @PotroNik как ответ опубликуете? )

Comment: Знать бы как это сделать. Я тут первый день =)

Comment: @insolor опубликуйте ответом ваш комментарий

Comment: @insolor, неплохо бы освоить `dos2unix` и `unix2dos` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В bash файлах окончания строк обязательно должны быть как в Linux (и *nix вообще) - только символ конца строки (line feed), а не как в Windows - возврат каретки (carriage return) + конец строки (line feed).

При передаче параметра в скрипт если в конце строки будет символ возврата каретки, то он будет передан как часть параметра скрипта. Поэтому, чтобы все работало корректно, нужно заменить символы конца строки на *nix вариант.

Типичный случай, когда я сталкивался с подобной проблемой - в начале файла стоит shebang (допустим, `#!/usr/bin/env python3`), но файл не запускается из-за того что в файле все концы  строк в Windows варианте, и к имени исполняемого файла в shebang прилепляется символ возврата каретки.